# why is 'import pyttsx3 as RVB' throwing a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, pip, syntax-error, pyttsx3

I was trying to create a text-to-speech code like EVERYBODY ELSE but for some reason when I type in this code.

```py
#pip3 install pyttsx3 
import pyttsx3 as RVB
text_speech = pyttsx3.init()
answer = input(hello)
text_speech.say(answer)
text_speech.runAndWait()
```

it says this in the terminal

```
[Running] python -u "/var/folders/7_/5j5858n91nzbx2yqlpq_w07m0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
  File "/var/folders/7_/5j5858n91nzbx2yqlpq_w07m0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 2
    import pyttsx3 as RVB
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.087 seconds
```

I have tried and tried with this code and it has yet to run, so can someone please help.

also, I have already installed pyttsx3------ using this command in the terminal

```sh
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

Comment: I removed some extra backticks assuming that they were an attempt at formatting content for the site. Please check that the content as-updated reflects what you actually meant to write.

Comment: If you use `as RVB`, why are you then trying to refer to the module under the `pyttsx3` name later? The whole point of `as` is to use a different name to refer to the module. You can (and should) take out the `as RVB` if you just want to refer to it as `pyttsx3`.

Comment: (...which is to say: Why do you have `as RVB` in your code at all?)

Comment: `[Running] python` What kind of environment is it? What is Python version? Can you check it with `python --version` ?